# Can we add a new column to the result set with out modifying the select in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query as:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col3, T2.col4 from Table1 T1 join Table2 T2
```

This returns the columns(T1,T2,T3,T4) as expected.

```
col1  col2    col3    col4
A      11      0.5     B
```

Now i want to add a column to the result set with out modifying the above `Select` statement.

I want output result set should have another column(col8) from Table1 but i cannot add this column(col8) to the exisiting `Select` statement.

```
    col1  col2    col3    col4   col8
    A      11      0.5     B       9
```

I know there is Union in SQL server. But Union requires

```
Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
The columns must also have similar data types
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order.
```

I want to achieve similar to UNION but with out above conditions. I want only column to be added to the result set.

Is this achievable in SQL Server?

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give me a sample table of input rows and expected output.

Comment: Please clarify: why can't you modify the query?? To make it short: NO, it's not possible! And UNION is not the same as adding a column to a query. It will result in additional rows and - as mentioned - requires same structure in both queries. However, if you'd use SSIS, you could add a derived column... anyways, simply extending the query would be way easier...

Comment: This seems like a nonsensical question, in all honesty. You use the `SELECT` clause to define the columns that will be returned in your statement. You can't change the columns that would be returned without changing the `SELECT` clause. Much like you can't change the table the data is returned from unless you change your `FROM` clause. This feels like an xy question.

Comment: @PawanKumar modified question with expected output

Comment: @Larnu How this can be nonsensical. if you know the answer tell yes or no. and thnks for the answer.

Comment: @Tyron78 i cannot modify bcos it has some where conditions in the select and my column doesnt satisfy the where condition

Comment: @Santosh, isn't that the real problem?  Why paper it over?

Comment: If you are allowed to do UNIONs then you might try something like: SELECT *, col8 FROM (SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col3, T2.col4 from Table1 T1 join Table2 T2) a. And with unions, you do not add new columns, you are adding new rows.

Comment: @Santosh Then you should think about extending the WHERE conditions. ;-) Another way might be: use your original query as subquery (or CTE) and JOIN (instead of UNION...) it to your T1 table.